# Merge "knowledge" and "epistemology" tags?

Tags: discussion, retagging, tag-synonyms

What is the consensus on merging or [symlinking](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201/how-does-the-tag-synonym-system-work) [knowledge](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge) and [epistemology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epistemology)? Are there any reasons why we should need both tags?

Although I was in favour of retaining [epistemology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epistemology) at first (probably because of academic jargon), it may be more useful to retain [knowledge](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge), as it is definitely a more **user-friendly option**.

Comment: If we were to consider this, I'd be in favor of using epistemology as the master, as it is the broader, more encompassing term. User-friendliness is less important than accuracy, and using the academic term will help people learn it. :)

Comment: User-friendliness is not a concern here if we create a synonym. Any time someone tries to use the tag `[knowledge]`, it will automatically map to the master tag, `[epistemology]`. (cc @stoicfury)

Comment: How would you tag the question [Are all facts worth knowing?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1641/73)  I don't think it's an [tag:epistemology] question.  (Some of the other [tag:knowledge] questions don't easily fit under [tag:epistemology], though many do, in my opinion.)

Comment: @Jon Good point. There are mainly two cat of tags in use on Phil.SE: _(sub)disciplines_ and _topics_. `[knowledge]` as a topic is not per se part of `[epistemology]` or `[phil-of-science]`. However, one part of http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1641/1582 has been discussed in phil of sci under the topic of _relevance_ as a requirement of scientific facts (opposed to, say, commonsense facts); the other part under the heading _ethical implications of science_. So the q can be tagged with those discipline-tags.

Comment: [tag:epistemology] would probably not be a good tag to use with AI and psychology knowledge-related questions. Epistemology is a form of meta-knowledge, and it is useful to be able to refer to the ground level.